# Possible to query against the count of an included key?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I have an application where I need to return the first user found that meets certain criteria, some of that criteria is having a certain number of objects stored.

For example, let's say I want to return the first store I can find that has at-least 3 employees with atleast two children. I know, what an odd-ball example. So I would have a query something like this:

```
PFUser.query()?
    .whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!)
    .includeKey("stores.employees.children")
    // .whereCountForkey("stores.employees", greaterThan: 2)
    // .whereCountForKey("stores.employees.children", greaterThan: 1)
    .getFirstObject();
```

Notice the commented out lines, I'm trying to find a way to do soemthing like this in a single query. I'm using parse, which I believe uses MongoDB on the back end, but I don't believe you can execute custom database queries..?

This is a mobile application for both iOS and Android, although the code shown is in SWIFT I have two variations of the project. Examples in either swift, obj-C, Java, or C# will be fine.

Also more than happy with Cloud-code solutions.

Answer (score -1):

There is an example in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries)

```
var Team = Parse.Object.extend("Team");
var teamQuery = new Parse.Query(Team);
teamQuery.greaterThan("winPct", 0.5);
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("hometown", "city", teamQuery);
userQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer the question that was given, this implies that a count was stored in the table, but in-fact, does not count the amount of documents stored. This would be done using the `$count` function on the backend, while this query executes the `$gt` function.